# How to move element above multiple containers in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a website using Bootstrap 3.
Part of this site are 4 div-containers:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="content" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3" style="background-color:#00F; color:#FFF">
            Menu
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-push-6 " style="background-color:#F00;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="visible-md visible-lg col-md-12" style="background-color:#F08;">
                    Mod_1
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#F80;">
                    Mod_2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-md-pull-3" style="background-color:#0F0;">
            Main content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Layout-View is shown here:

[image]

Code on [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/mB8QV/)
"Mod_1" is only visible in the desktop view like expected. "Mod_2" should move above the Menu and Main container in the tablet view, but I can't find a way to place the container on top of both of them.

I already tried to use the col-sm-[colnumber]-push and -pull classes. But I didn't get the right results.

Comment: Use id for the divs, grab your desire div with javascript and push it where you want it to appear. you can use $(window).resize to figure out when your window is resizing. And if you like the js approach, I can tell you more as a answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I only wanted to use Bootstrap, no more additional scripting. So its not exactly what I'm searching for.